# Add constraints to arcs in CVRP

Tags: python, or-tools, traveling-salesman

I want to define a problem in Google OR-Tools, in which I can apply the [CVRP](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/cvrp#python_3) with constraints on the arcs. In my situation, the arcs between two points are predefined connections, where NOT all points are connected to each other; comparable to a partly-connected undirected graph as shown in this image.

[image]

**I want to enforce an arc bandwidth constraint**: multiple vehicles are allowed in our graph, but each arc (a.k.a. connection) must only allow an x number of vehicles at a time.

The number of vehicles on an arc are dependend on the travel time between two nodes.

Comment: If you got a CVRP, i guess you already do some capacity-based aggregation. Maybe you can extend this idea to your *travel-times*? In the routing-solver this kind of abstraction would be probably coined: *RoutingDimension*.